# Retriving the array values from json string

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, json

I have a cart array (JavaScript array) in my web application where I store different products. And each product has different specifications (i.e. URL, name, price, quantity, total price) which is again stored in an array.

So it forms an array of arrays. I need to save this cart to a database.

To persist it to database I need to get these arrays in a Java class and then save to database.

How can I take this array to database?

My array which is in json format goes goes like this (dummy array):

```
{"products":[{"productURL":"images/product/a.jpg","productName":"Headfones 1","productPrice":"234","productQuantity":"2","productTotal":"468"},
{"productURL":"images/product/b.jpg","productName":"Headfones 2","productPrice":"234","productQuantity":"3","productTotal":"702"},
{"productURL":"images/product/d.jpg","productName":"Headfones 4","productPrice":"234","productQuantity":"1","productTotal":"234"},
{"productURL":"images/product/d.jpg","productName":"Headfones 4","productPrice":"234","productQuantity":"6","productTotal":"1404"}]}
```

any library for parsing json??

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen ya... i have mySQL data base..

Comment: Send the JSON to a web service and then return back as an application.

Answer (score 0):

Send the JavaScript array in JSON format to the server. Then parse JSON on the server and convert to a Java array. I'd recommend the [Jackson JSON](http://jackson.codehaus.org) parser. This is a working example:

```java
    String JSON = "[[\"images/product/a.jpg\",\"Headfones 1\",\"234\",3,702],"
            + "[\"images/product/b.jpg\",\"Headfones 2\",\"234\",4,936],"
            + "[\"images/product/c.jpg\",\"Headfones 3\",\"234\",5,1170]]";
    String[][] products = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
            JSON, 
            new TypeReference<String[][]>() {});
```

With the `products` array, you can now start writing the data to the database.